# How to convert leads without setting opportunity to closed won?

Tags: opportunity, leads, lead-conversion

Whenever I convert `Leads`, and create an `Opportunity` on the go, all these Opportunities get the status `Closed Won`. I could not find where to change that, as it's obviously nonsense.

How to change that?

Comment: I'm assuming you have stages that are not categorized as Closed/Won. What stages are available in your Sales Process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe when Converting a Lead, it sets the Opportunity Stage to the first Stage listed in your Sales Process. Please check the first stage in the Sales Process that pertains to your Opportunity (depending on the Record Type)

Comment: Yes, it is as simple as this! Salesforce just takes the first entry and sets the opportunity to this stage.